# Custom component not loading in ig-grid column template

Tags: angularjs, ignite-ui, iggrid

I'm trying to use custom made component in ig-grid column template. Component is rendered correctly in Html, but it never reaches component's constructor. How is it possible to use custom component in column template?

```
<script id="colTmpl" type="text/template">
    <custom-component data="${datatouse}"></custom-component>
</script>

<div>
    <ig-grid id="grid1" data-source="vm.datasource" width="100%" primary-key="Id" auto-generate-columns="false" autocommit="true">
        <columns>
            <column key="Id" header-text="Id" width="50px" data-type="number" hidden="hidden"></column>
            <column key="datatouse" width="100%" header-text="my custom component" datatype="object" template="{{getHtml('#colTmpl')}}"></column>
        </columns>
    </ig-grid>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the Ignite UI templating (`$.ig.tmpl`) and apply your custom component to the cells.

```
$.ig.tmpl = function (tmpl, data) {
    angCells.push($compile(tmpl)($scope));
    return "";
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dkamburov/agps9oof/).

Comment: Thank you for answering. However, my ig-grid is also in component, so there is no $scope or $compile. Is it possible to override IgniteUI templating inside component? I already solved above problem by using simple ng-repeat instead of ig-grid, but it would be nice to get this working in case of future implementations.

Comment: Sure, you can override the IgniteUI template wherever you want. But if you want to use AngularJS templating instead, you need to $compile the template in order to get fully functional AngularJS component or directive.

Comment: Okay, so there is no way to get this working without using $compile. Thank you, I guess I need to use directive instead of component next time I need ig-grid like this.